# Which preposition is correct in "We can schedule a call (on/at) either of the following options"?

Tags: prepositions

> - We can schedule a call on either of the following options
> - We can schedule a call at either of the following options

How to write it correctly, do I need to use on either/at either?
Please help me to write a business email.

Comment: Can you give more context please?

Comment: Depending on the nature of the *(**two**)* contextually-relevant options, you might be able to link that reference to the basic statement ***We can schedule a call*** using something like ***using*** (or even ***following***, except that's a bit awkward if the same word is going to be immediately repeated as a slightly different usage), but I don't think a simple preposition like ***on*** or ***at*** would ever be idiomatic in the cited context.

Comment: I would use **about**: *We can schedule a call **about** either of the following options: …*